# join Javascript embed code

Tags: javascript, blogger

This is about a Blogger template called Bloggertube
Its originally coded to embed youtube videos and grab url image and post the image thumbnail

I also modified to work with Dailymotion

But I'm pretty newbie at Javascript, and I'm trying to figure out how to make a condition to make them work at same time, and also add more sites in the future

function *createVideoThumb* refers to thumbnail creation

function *createVideoThumb2* refers to player's embed code

**The blogger post sintax is:**

(youtube link)endofvid

[starttext]
(post text)
[endtext]

Youtube code:

```
function createVideoThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if (div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")!=-1){
      var vidid = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")+31,div.innerHTML.indexOf("endofvid"));
    }else {var vidid =""};  
    var postlink = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[postlink]")+10,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[/postlink]"));    
    if (vidid ==""){var imgvid ='<a href="'+ postlink + '"><img  class="thumbnail" src="http://i195.photobucket.com/albums/z105/dantearaujo/novideo.png" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a>';
                   }else{
                     var imgvid ='<a href="'+ postlink + '"><img  class=thumbnail src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+vidid+'/mqdefault.jpg" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a>';
                   };
    var summary = imgvid ;
    div.innerHTML = summary;
  }
  function createVideoThumb2(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if (div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")!=-1){
      var vidid = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")+31,div.innerHTML.indexOf("endofvid"));
    }else {var vidid =""};
    var textinside = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[starttext]")+11,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[endtext]"));
    var postlink = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[postlink]")+10,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[/postlink]"));
    var embedvid = "";
    if (vidid!="") {
      embedvid = '<object width="654" height="393"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ vidid + '&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ vidid + '&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="654" height="393"></embed></object>'
    }
    var summary =  embedvid + '<div class="content">' + textinside  + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
  }
```

Dailymotion code

```
function createVideoThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if (div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")!=-1){
      var vidid = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")+33,div.innerHTML.indexOf("endofvid"));
    }else {var vidid =""};  
    var postlink = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[postlink]")+10,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[/postlink]"));    
    if (vidid ==""){var imgvid ='<a href="'+ postlink + '"><img  class="thumbnail" src="http://i195.photobucket.com/albums/z105/dantearaujo/novideo.png" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a>';
                   }else{
                     var imgvid ='<a href="'+ postlink + '"><img  class=thumbnail src=" http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/'+vidid+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></a>';
                   };
    var summary = imgvid ;
    div.innerHTML = summary;
  }
  function createVideoThumb2(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if (div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")!=-1){
      var vidid = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")+33,div.innerHTML.indexOf("endofvid"));
    }else {var vidid =""};
    var textinside = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[starttext]")+11,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[endtext]"));
    var postlink = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[postlink]")+10,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[/postlink]"));
    var embedvid = "";
    if (vidid!="") {
      embedvid = '<iframe frameborder="0" width="654" height="393" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/'+ vidid +'" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }
    var summary =  embedvid + '<div class="content">' + textinside  + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where your problem is. The solution is to only have 2 functions: createVideoThumb and createVideoThumb2. In the start of the functions, make a check what the inner html contains. For example:

```
function createVideoThumb2(pID){

    // Dailymotion
    if (div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")!=-1){

        // Set specific local vars here

    }
    // Youtube
    else if(div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")!=-1) {

        // Set specific local vars here

    }

    // .... More providers

    // Use specific local vars in the code below (I didnt edit anything below)

    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if (div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")!=-1){
      var vidid = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("http://www.dailymotion.com/video/")+33,div.innerHTML.indexOf("endofvid"));
    }else {var vidid =""};
    var textinside = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[starttext]")+11,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[endtext]"));
    var postlink = div.innerHTML.substring(div.innerHTML.indexOf("[postlink]")+10,div.innerHTML.indexOf("[/postlink]"));
    var embedvid = "";
    if (vidid!="") {
      embedvid = '<iframe frameborder="0" width="654" height="393" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/'+ vidid +'" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
    }
    var summary =  embedvid + '<div class="content">' + textinside  + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
  }
```

You can do this for both functions, and then use the vars throughout the rest of the function. Vars should be like iframeWidth, iframeHeight,... and so on, whatever you need customised for each provider.